# Registering webhooks with non-secure URLs

Tags: web, ssl-certificate

I have a web service that provides users the ability to register webhooks with secure URLs (e.g. https://). I am considering also supporting non-secured URLs to be registered (e.g. self-signed certs).

Would my service be exposed to any security vulnerabilities if I enable users to register non-secured URLs? I'm aware the user registering the non-secured URL would be exposed, but would my service be exposed in any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: No

Explanation: Your service is calling a 3rd party URL which is not under your control. So for you it does not matter if the communication to this url is encrypted or not. From your point of view, both types of URLs should not be trusted (i.e. you should not execute the response payload).

Edit: remind to implement this carefully. Especially do skip SSL validation only for the particular web hook you call, not globally for your application.

Comment: Thanks for your response!